# Layout with Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Below is the code of a view in our project. I want a formpanel and a button in a vbox layout. I want to center the button horizontally.

```
Ext.define('Coder.view.membership.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'membershiploginview',

    requires: ['Ext.field.Password'],

    config: {
        title: 'Membership',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'center',
            pack: 'center'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'formpanel',
                items: [
                    { xtype: 'textfield', name: 'userName', label: 'User ID' },
                    { xtype: 'passwordfield', name: 'password', label: 'Password' }
                ],
                height: 300,
                flex: 1
            },
            { xtype: 'button', text: 'Login' }
        ]
    }
})
```

With this configuration, the formpanel takes all available space vertically but none of the controls in it are visible. I can see the button centered horizontally where the formpanel ends. Why can't I see the controls in the formpanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `vbox` layout:

1. `pack: center` will placed items in the middle vertically.
2. `align: center` will placed items in the middle horizontally.

Your form panel didn't show up because you do not specify any width for your form so your form will obviously takes `width: 100%` as default, therefore your config `align: center` get conflict.

To make it works, you should either remove that config or specify a width for your form panel.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this code,

```
{ 
  xtype: 'button', 
  text: 'Login' 
}
```

Use it like this:

```
title   : 'Membership',            
items   : [
    {
        xtype   : 'formpanel',
        items: [
            { xtype: 'textfield', name: 'userName', label: 'User ID' },
            { xtype: 'passwordfield', name: 'password', label: 'Password' }
        ],
        height : 300
    },{
        layout : {
            type : 'vbox',
            align : 'center'
        },
        items : [{ 
            xtype: 'button', 
            text: 'Login',
            width : 100 
        }]
    }
]
```

It takes `layout:'auto'` by default and puts the button at the center.

Answer (score 0):

you give the login button Style like margin-left and margin right

```
                {
                                xtype:'button',
                                ui:'decline',
                                style: 'font-size: .8em; border:#A4A4A4 solid 1px;border-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius:6px ;-webkit-border-radius:6px ; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px; height:40px',
                                html:'<font color="white">Sign In</font>',
                                action:'signIn'
                              },
```